# Multiple Ring Buffer Tool Stopped Working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, error-000210, buffer

The Multiple Ring Buffer tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1 stopped working.  It worked fine, now won't work at all.  It doesn't matter where I send the output, I get the "Error 000210: Cannot create output".  Again, it doesn't matter where I send the output, what I call it or anything.  Even the defaults don't work.

Comment: If your input source is either a 1) shapefile, or 2) file geodatabase feature class, or 3) a personal geodatabase feature class, it may be corrupted.  Run the *Check Geometry* tool, and if errors are reported run the *Repair Geometry* tool.  Then re-run your multi-buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.  scratch.gdb was corrupted.  Deleted it and created a new scratch.gdb and am back up and running

Comment: For the future people who are interested in your solution it would help if you edited your answer to include the path lication to your scratch.gdb